# How to get file resources instantly?

Tags: android, performance

When I see an Android app using files like videos, photos, songs these things get displayed already at the moment of opening. I tried to query all of these in my app and I have to wait a few hundred milliseconds even if I have only 100 songs. When I want to get images or videos it takes about the same time. How do apps seen on Google Play can accomplish this loading speed? They're also able to (for example) create widgets using this information (music player widget) before loading the app and finding the files.

An example of how I load songs:

```
final String[] mediaProjection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_MODIFIED,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,};

    ContentResolver songResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = songResolver.query(musicUri, mediaProjection, null, null, null);

    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int albumIdColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
        int artistIdColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID);
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int albumColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int durationColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
        int yearColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR);
        int dateAddedColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED);
        int dateModifiedColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_MODIFIED);
        int pathColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        do {
            long songId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            long songAlbumId = musicCursor.getLong(albumIdColumn);
            long songArtistId = musicCursor.getLong(artistIdColumn);
            String songTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String songAlbum = musicCursor.getString(albumColumn);
            String songArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            long songDuration = musicCursor.getLong(durationColumn);
            int songYear = musicCursor.getInt(yearColumn);
            int songDateAdded = musicCursor.getInt(dateAddedColumn);
            int songDateModified = musicCursor.getInt(dateModifiedColumn);
            String songPath = musicCursor.getString(pathColumn);


                // Add these things into a list
                // ...
            }
        } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (musicCursor != null) {
        musicCursor.close();
    }

    return true;
```

Comment: Can you post a sample snippet of your code when you "...query all of these in my app..." ?

Answer (score 0):

Use androids content provider class to quickly load media files to your application.

Android content provider acts as a middle layer between application and storage providing ease in use.

So suppose you want to load all images then just query    content provider media/External/ image database and you will be able to quickly load data.  Same way for music library.